# Retrieve data from database

Tags: c#, sql, database

I need to use C# to get data from database(sql) and the data in database is updated every few seconds. So do I have to make a loop or there is a better way to do that? Is it possible that when database is updating, the program can wait until it finishes updating? thx!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Query notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx) in ADO.Net. These allow your code to be notified by SQL Server whenever the results of a particular query change.